# Can i check value of onclick="" with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a ajax / php pagination system and having some problem adding the class active to the right link to style it as selected.

So my question is can I get the value of onlclick="" with jquery?

My links are shown as:

```
<li><a href='#' onclick='fetchResults(" + adResultsData.pages[i] + ");'>" + adResultsData.pages[i] + "</a></li>
```

Now I want to see what number is inside onclick="fetchResults()" then add the class
highlightActivePage if it is the current active link/page.

Example:

Lets say that I clicked on link 5,  which is:

```
<li><a href='#' onclick='fetchResults(5);'>5</a></li>
```

I already have a function to check/output current page which is:

```
adResultsData.current_page
```

aka

```
paginationHTML += pageSpan.innerHTML = "<br>Page " + adResultsData.current_page + " of " + adResultsData.number_of_pages;
```

is it somehow possible to add the class "highlightActivePage" to the a-tag with same value as
adResultsData.current_page ?

Sorry if is seems a bit messy,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following as a quick fix (not the most elegant).

Instead of showing the value 5 directly into the function fetchResults(), create an attribute
that will be used only for that purpose, let's say "page" or "p" for shorter code.

You should have then:

```
<li><a href='#' p='5' onclick='fetchResults(this);'>5</a></li>
```

Put the keyword "this" into your function. Then your function could have something like that:

```
function fetchResults(this) {
    $(this).addClass('highlightActivePage');
    // more code....
}
```

this will represent the a node which is clicked.

Hope it helps.

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the value of the onclick attribute.

So $(your_element).attr('onclick')